# Set Intersection with asymmetric set sizes

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, sets

I'm looking for an algorithm to perform set intersection where set $N_1$ is very small and set $N_2$ is very large.

Due to the constraints of the problem I am solving, I cannot rely on an algorithm which sorts or depends on sorted elements.  Further, the simple method of performing $N_1$ hash look ups in a hash table of size at least $N_2$ will also not work.

Are there any non-naive approaches to this problem that I am missing?
They do not have to be as efficient as either approach, but obviously the more performant the better.

Edit:  Since my constraints were a bit vague, I'll go ahead and spell them out.

The application I have in mind is one type of [MPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_multi-party_computation). Here, I would like to perform a set intersection while neither party reveals anything about the elements that are not in the intersection. One party will be performing the comparisons, and the other party will be transmitting the elements of their set in an encrypted format.

Sorting is out because an encrypted value cannot be evaluated for anything besides equality. Doing so would either reveal more about the elements in the set or would come with significant computational overhead.

Hash table look ups have great promise, but all approaches involving them require that both parties pretend they have a set size of $max(N_1, N_2)$. The most effective way to optimize the communication between the parties is hash tables, but privacy requires inserting enough false elements so that each bin of the hash table has the same number of items.

Bloom filters also suffer from similar problems as hash tables.  To be correct and secure, the size of the smaller bloom filter must be large enough to fit the larger set.

I'm really just looking for a fundamentally different algorithm that I can use to design a different approach to the problem. I would like for the communication and computation to be dominated by the size of the smaller set. I recognize that this is a research problem that no one will have a perfect solution to. Instead, I am trying to find different types of structure that can be used to improve on the naive approach.

Comment: Any non-naive approach is going to exploit some structural aspect of the data.  So what exactly is this set data that resists both sorting and hashing?

Comment: If you have the leeway (and willingness) to pick particular data structures, Realz Slaw's answer to [this question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/17984/computing-set-difference-between-two-large-sets) could be useful.

Comment: I agree; we need to know a) which set representation(s) you (can) use, and b) whatever you know about the data.

Comment: @Raphael I spelled out my constraints quite a bit more.  The elements in the set can be translated into any arbitrary structure, but the security constraints require that the structure not reveal the value of the elements.  If you want more background on the problem, see this recent [paper](http://eprint.iacr.org/2014/447.pdf).

Comment: I still find this confusing.  I know about MPC, but I don't understand why hash tables require both parties pretend they have a set size of $\max(N_1,N_2)$.  Can you elaborate?  And can you elaborate on what precisely is your model?  Are you looking for a circuit?  What are the inputs to the circuit?  What is your measure of the complexity of the circuit?  Right now the question is not very specific.

Comment: @D.W. I will not be using garbled circuits.  If I can manage, it will use only OTE. If a hash bin does not have the same number of elements as all of the others, then it reveals information about one set.  Having an empty bin is even worse as it reveals that your set has no elements that are in the preimage of all $k$ hash functions. The reason my question is vague is because I would like to consider all possible fundamental **algorithms** for doing this rather than focus on the crypto primitives.

Comment: @Guest, apologies if this is a basic question, but remind me what you mean by OTE?  Oblivious transfer?  Something else?  (And I presume you are familiar with existing protocols for private set intersection? e.g., http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/12828/351, http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2627/351, http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14925/351, http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/443/351)

Comment: @D.W. Thanks for the links. I am already quite familiar with many of the existing protocols.  By OTE I meant Oblivious Transfer Extension. If you look at the benchmarks on [page 13](http://eprint.iacr.org/2014/447.pdf) you will see why I want to use an OTE based approach.  All of the existing practical protocols that I have studied in depth do not lend themselves to optimizing for the smaller set. (I would love to be wrong if you can point to anything) This is what fuels my interest in learning about any possible algorithmic approaches that haven't been explored.

Comment: OK.  Sounds like your goals are the same as http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/12828/351.  And the comment there seems like it applies here too: any protocol will have to touch every bit of both sets (otherwise it is not secure).  So, I don't see any hope to have a scheme whose computation complexity is dominated by the size of the smaller set.  (In contrast, if we ignore security, it's easy to get a protocol whose communication complexity is dominated by the size of the smaller set: simply send the smaller set to the other endpoint.)  Does this help frame a more specific question?

Answer (score 2):

If you have exactly one intersection to compute, building a hash table from $N_1$ and doing $N_2$ lookups goes through the same number of hash operations as building one from $N_2$ and doing $N_1$ lookups.

Comment: Now that I've spelled out my constraints, I think it's clear this solution doesn't contribute a lot.  Thanks for the thought.

Comment: @Guest, alas, it's not clear to me yet.  Thanks for editing the question, as it helped partially, but I think I need more explanation to understand.